# Android Get Group of Contact by ID

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, contacts

I have a contact ID, how do I get the group the contact is assigned to? I am sure it is something to do with the Contacts.Groups class but I cannot figure it out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `GroupMembership.PERSON_ID` you have the ID of the Person, and in the same table `GroupMembership.GROUP_ID` you have the ID of the group. You can retrieve the groups with the `Contacts.Groups`.

Remember that in every "table" there is and unique ID to identify the row.

Hope this helps. (Im working on it too)