# how to get the group id of a contact in android

Tags: android, android-contacts, contactscontract

I want to get the group id of each contact in my android application.I have initial query like this

```
Cursor cursor = cr.query(Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                new String[] { 
                Phone.CONTACT_ID}, null, null, null);
```

And what i do is get details of each which related to this CONTACT_ID.I have manage to get phone number,names,addresses and emails so far but still couldn't manage to get the group id of the contact.

P.S i found a question asked before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/657154/559185) but the class `android.provider.Contacts.GroupMembership` is deprecated.

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
final String selection = "mimetype_id = (select _id from mimetypes where mimetype = \"" + 
        vnd.android.cursor.item / group_membership + "\")";

Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(Data.CONTENT_URI,
        new String[]{Phone.CONTACT_ID}, selection, null, null);
try {
    if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            Log.i("Details", "Contact IDs" + cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(Phone.CONTACT_ID)));
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
} finally {
    if (cursor != null) {
        cursor.close();
    }
}
```